# How to safely use callbacks when the bound function could be deleted

Tags: c++, c++11, callback

In the following code, we are creating an object, bind one function and call it before then after deleting the object.

This obviously leads to a segmentation fault as the underlying object was used after deletion.

In the context of a library providing callbacks for asynchronous data, how are we supposed to prevent callback functions to point to a `nullptr`?

You can test at cpp.sh/5ubbg

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class CallbackContainer {
 public:
  std::string data_;
  CallbackContainer(std::string data): data_(data) {}
  ~CallbackContainer() {}
  void rawTest(const std::string& some_data);
};

void CallbackContainer::rawTest(const std::string& some_data) {
  std::cout << data_ << " " << some_data << std::endl;
}

int main(int /* argc */, char const** /* argv */) {
  std::unique_ptr<CallbackContainer> container;
  container.reset(new CallbackContainer("Internal data"));

  auto callback = std::bind(&CallbackContainer::rawTest, container.get(), std::placeholders::_1);
  callback("Before");
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  container.reset();
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  callback("After");
  return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
> Internal data Before 
> 0x7178a3bf6570 
> 0x7178a3bf6570 
> Error launching program (Segmentation fault)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a followup, we decided to use [roscpp method](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/d82f3f09f2b9b55cbbee68ba25f36174ec2c7002/clients/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h#L528-L530) which is similar to Alex Guteniev's proposition.

Instead of doing `std::bind` explicitly, we use it internally and keep the parent as `std::weak_ptr<const void>` pointer to the `std::shared_ptr<P>` (as it would conflict with unique_ptr).

The API looks like:

```cpp
  std::shared_ptr<Container> container;
  queue.subscribe(&Container::callback_method, container);
```

The subscription function is as following with T the explicit type of the data (Class-wise) but P the implicit class of the Parent class (Container in this case).

```cpp
template <class P>
std::shared_ptr<ThreadedQueue<T>> subscribe(void (P::*function_pointer)(std::shared_ptr<const T>), std::shared_ptr<P> parent, size_t queue_size = -1) {
  callback_ = std::bind(function_pointer, parent.get(), std::placeholders::_1);
  parent_ = std::weak_ptr<const void>(parent);
}
```

When calling the callback, we do the following check:

```cpp
if(auto lock = parent_.lock()) {
  callback_(data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way I prefer while working with [boost asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html):

I faced the same issue while working with [boost asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). We need to register callbacks to `io_service` and it was difficult to implement some sort of `Manager` class which manages lifetime of the objects we may create.

So, I implement something that was suggested by [Michael Caisse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwOv_tw2eA4) in cppcon2016. I started passing the `shared_ptr` to the object to the `std::bind`.

I used to extend the lifetime of the object and in the callback, you can decide to either extend the lifetime of the object again (by registering the callback again) or let it die automatically.

```
std::shared_ptr<MyClass> ptr = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
auto func = std::bind(&MyClass::MyMemFunc, this, ptr);
ptr.reset();
```

> In the context of a library providing callbacks for asynchronous data, how are we supposed to prevent callback functions to point to a nullptr?

I wouldn't say that's the best solution but using by my above approach, you can detect if you need to proceed further in your callback or not.

It might not be the efficient way but it won't cause any undefined behavior.

```
void CallbackContainer::rawTest(const std::string& some_data, std::shared<CallbackContainer> ptr) 
{
    if (ptr.use_count() == 1) {
        // We are the only owner of the object.
        return; // and the object dies after this
    }
    std::cout << data_ << " " << some_data << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**

An example code that shows how to do it using [std::enable_shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>


class ABCD: public std::enable_shared_from_this<ABCD> {
public:
    void call_me_anytime()
    {
        std::cout << "Thanks for Calling Me" << std::endl;
    }

public:
    ABCD(void)
    {
        std::cout << "CONSTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
    }

    ~ABCD(void)
    {
        std::cout << "DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<ABCD>();
    auto cb = std::bind(&ABCD::call_me_anytime, ptr->shared_from_this());
    ptr.reset();

    std::cout << "RESETING SHARED_PTR" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "CALLING CALLBACK" << std::endl;
    cb();
    std::cout << "RETURNING" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
CONSTRUCTOR
RESETING SHARED_PTR
CALLING CALLBACK
Thanks for Calling Me
RETURNING
DESTRUCTOR
```

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't answer the question. You are extending the lifetime of an object not preventing the function to be called when the pointer has been reset. I would expect something like `if (safe to call) callback(); else throw;`

Comment: In the callback, we can decide if we need to proceed or not! To check the ref count of the shared_ptr that has been passed?

Comment: Ok. But what if you have two binds that point to the same faulty pointer. Than you have two ref counts. You would have to implement some logic that counts the binds against the ref count and decide when it's safe or not. I think there must be an easier way.

Comment: I suspect there is some other nice way to achieve it. I think something needs to be done around `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Happy to learn. If someone posts some better answer, i will take mine down!

Comment: I think the solution can be enhanced by using weak_ptr: `auto wptr = std::weak_ptr<MyClass>(ptr); auto func = [this, wptr] { auto ptr = wptr.lock(); if (ptr) ptr->MyMemFunc(); };`

Answer (score 3):

If you can share ownership, do this:

```
int main(int /* argc */, char const** /* argv */) {
  std::shared_ptr<CallbackContainer> container; // shared pointer
  container.reset(new CallbackContainer("Internal data"));
  // shared with functor
  auto callback = std::bind(&CallbackContainer::rawTest, container, std::placeholders::_1); 
  callback("Before");
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  container.reset();
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  callback("After");
  return 0;
}
```

If not, you should somehow pass invalidity to function object explicitly.
This assumes that you know when container is deleted, and manually invalidate explicitly *before* that:

```
int main(int /* argc */, char const** /* argv */) {
  std::unique_ptr<CallbackContainer> container;
  container.reset(new CallbackContainer("Internal data"));
  std::atomic<CallbackContainer*> container_raw(container.get());
  auto callback = [&container_raw] (std::string data)
  {
    if (auto c = container_raw.load())
      c->rawTest(data);
  };
  callback("Before");
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  container_raw.store(nullptr);
  container.reset();
  std::cout << &callback << std::endl;
  callback("After");
  return 0;
}
```

For asio cases, usually `shared_from_this()` is used, like `std::bind(&MyClass::MyMemFunc, shared_from_this(), ptr);`

Comment: There is one problem. If `container_raw ` is also being accessed in another thread and hence you are reading it in another thread, then could create `race conditions`.

Comment: You need to use `mutex` to avoid that. I still think `shared_ptr` would be better idea to use.

Comment: I agree now that `shared_ptr` is a good idea for your case. But thre are cases where you don't own container, in that case `shared_ptr` may not be convenient. I edited my code to prevent race condition.

Comment: Nope! Even if you are storing it in `atomic` variable, someone might delete that pointer and you will be holding dangling pointer!

Comment: Sure, you have to know when the other pointer is deleted and clear `atomic` in advance. If you don't, even `mutex` wouldn't help, only `shared_ptr` would work.